# JPA find() method with vendor-specific properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and I have started using it recently. I have a doubt with the following method which was introduced in JPA 2.0 -

```
 public <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey, 
                  Map<String, Object> properties);
```

The documentation says, **Find by primary key, using the vendor specified properties.**

But I am unable to understand what are those vendor specific properties and under what situation this overloaded find() method should be used.

Can any one explain this to me with a suitable example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read it as DB vendor specific properties, more like hints.

Comment: What type of hints... Can you specify some?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215), it's a list of query hints for `Hibernate`. For `Eclipselink` you can use [these](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints) hints.

You can use hints in property map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("org.hibernate.cacheMode", CacheMode.REFRESH);
MyClass myClass = em.find(MyClass.class, 1L, map);
```

Comment: Got you. Thanks. I would have upvoted your answer only if I had 15 reputation.